# Kubernetes ingress routing rules for Asp.net Core Application gives 404 error while other routes is working

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use kubernetes ingress rules to navigate my traffic to different microservices developed using asp.net core (core 5). I have tested those microservices after deploying to the kubernetes (docker desktop local cluster) and those are working as expected (at least swagger UI and related actions through the swagger).

Now, I like to use the kubernetes ingress rules to navigate them. somehow for all the navigations, I am getting 404 not found error. Just to confirm whether the rules are working, I have used the hashicorp/http-echo (with Apple and Banana) and those are coming.

I feel that something wrong with the way asp.net core (dynamic version) serving the request. something to do with the asp.net profile but I am not too sure what is wrong.

Here is my configurations (everything is in same namespace):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: shoppingcart-api-gateway-rules
  namespace: local-shoppingcart-v1
  # annotations:
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressclassName: nginx
  rules: 
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /webapp1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend: 
          service: 
            name: webappsample1-service
            port: 
              number: 30021
      - path: /apple
        pathType: Prefix
        backend: 
          service:
            name: my-apple-service
            port: 
              number: 30101
```

here is my curl request and response

```
request: curl http://localhost:31242/apple
response: apple
  ## now the asp.net based routing testing.....
request: curl http://localhost:31242/webapp1
response: <no response> 
  ## with curl -v or curl -i it gives status code 404 Not Found
```

asp.net application launchSettings.json file

```
"WebAppSample1": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
  "applicationUrl": "http://+:5000"   <<--- It was http://localhost:5000 previously.
}
```

On the startup.cs file, I have also added the

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
```

On kubernetes deployment file, I have added environment variable too.

deployment.yaml

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webappsample1
    image: webappsample1
    env:
    - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
      value: http://+:80
    - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
      value: Development
    ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort: 80
```

service.yaml

```
spec:
type: NodePort
selector:
  app: webappsample1
ports:
- protocol: TCP
  nodePort: 30021
  port: 30021
  targetPort: http
  name: http-webappsample1
```

manually, testing the webappsample1 through http://localhost:30021 (nodePort) and confirm that application is working.

[image]

finally, the ingress (as I have used nginx ingress controller) here is the service which expose that outside the cluster.

```
kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
```

```html
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.110.88.166   <none>        80:31242/TCP,443:32353/TCP   6d20h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.102.222.57   <none>        443/TCP                      6d20h
```

Comment: try with specifying ti ingress class name in the annotation.

Comment: nope. no difference. same 404 error.

Comment: @BrijeshShah did you found a solution for this? because I'm facing the same problem. for me everything works just fine if the Ingress rules Prefix point to the root "/" only, if I  try to use dinamics folder I get a 404.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. In the ApplicationURL for launchSettings.json you can have http://localhost:5000 and the similar to it, you need to expose the the port you want from pod. let me know if you want both the file. I might forward you that for your reference if that helps.

Comment: @BrijeshShah, I am also facing same issue. Could you please send me all the YAML files, docker files, etc over mail, ajmal.yazdani@gmail.com

Comment: Ok - have sent you some of the files. see if that helps you further in your troubleshooting.